# how to count array which keys has values exists?

Tags: php

```
 $count = array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three', 4=>'');
```

There are four values of array and one key has no values.

I would like to show number of count of array which key has values.

Comment: I'm guessing `3 => ''three` is a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$array = array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three', 4=>'');
$count = count(array_filter($array));
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter` and filter out all keys whose value is not empty

```
print_r(array_filter($count, create_function('$value', 'return $value !== "";')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use functions array_filter() and count()    
$fullarray = array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three', 4=>'');
$filteredArray = array_filter($fullarray);//filters the values of an array using a callback function
$count=count($filteredArray);//returns the number of elements in an array.
print_r($count);//display count
```